# Flutter intl generated files, null safety problem

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, localization, intl

The current flutter version of my project is 2.2.3 and the version of my intl library is 0.17.0. When I add a new value to any of my language files, I get null safety syntax insertions in my messages_all and l10n files in my generated file.
*Code snippets :*

```
MessageLookupByLibrary? _findExact(String localeName) {
  switch (localeName) {
    case 'ar':
      return messages_ar.messages;
    case 'de':
      return messages_de.messages;
    case 'en':
      return messages_en.messages;
    case 'fr':
      return messages_fr.messages;
    case 'ru':
      return messages_ru.messages;
    case 'tr':
      return messages_tr.messages;
    default:
      return null;
  }
}
```

`MessageLookByLibrary?`

When i edit my language files :

```
flutter pub global run intl_utils:generate
INFO: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_ar, assuming 'ar' based on the file name.
INFO: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_de, assuming 'de' based on the file name.
INFO: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_en, assuming 'en' based on the file name.
INFO: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_fr, assuming 'fr' based on the file name.
INFO: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_ru, assuming 'ru' based on the file name.
INFO: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_tr, assuming 'tr' based on the file name.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Errors like this,

[image]

If I haven't made any changes, I don't get an error, but when I make the slightest change, the same errors repeat.

[image]

Comment: Please provide your error message and a bit more context

Comment: I added more info

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with the newest version (2.5.1) of intl_utils installed. What fixed it for me was deactivating and reactivating intl_utils.

First

```
flutter pub global deactivate intl_utils
```

And then reinstall the latest version

```
flutter pub global activate intl_utils 2.5.1
```

Comment: This solved my situation, deactivating and just activating (without specifying any version number)

Answer (score 3):

check if you have the latest intl_utils installed.

```
flutter pub global list
```

If you haven't installed the latest version run this command.
You can check the latest version [here](https://pub.dev/packages/intl_utils)

```
flutter pub global activate intl_utils 2.4.1
```

Be sure that the package name is intl_utils

This helped me at least.

Cheers